# Focus on HTML element with document-level onkeydown event

Tags: javascript

When I press the 'p' key, I want a specific text box to come into focus. To do that, I set up an onkeydown listener on the document:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'p': {
            document.getElementById('test').focus();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I press 'p', the input does receive focus, but it also types the letter 'p' into the input, which I don't want. I just want focus on the empty text box. When I tried adding e.preventDefault to the listener, that stopped the 'p' from showing up, but it also prevented me from typing anything into the text box at all.

How can I focus on the text box without it typing in the shortcut key? If at all possible, I'd like to accomplish this in pure JavaScript.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qau6woL6/

Comment: Should `p` character be allowed to be typed at `input` after element gains focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only change the focus if the element is not already focused. In addition, only prevent the default if you are changing the focus. This will allow you to type <kbd>p</kbd> into the `<input>` after the first <kbd>p</kbd> is used to set the focus.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var desiredEl = document.getElementById('test');
    if(desiredEl.contains(document.activeElement)){
        return;
    }
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'p': {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(window.InstallTrigger){
                //Is Firefox
                //Use setTimeout to work around a Firefox bug that prevents input
                //  if the focus is set here directly. Only noticed in Stack Overflow's
                //  snippet environment. Did not show up in JSFiddle. Not seen on
                //  Chrome. If the 250ms delay (100ms does not work) is unacceptable,
                //  then some other workaround can be found. Can shave to 200ms, but
                //  the minimal time required is undetermined. If that time varies by
                //   system performance is unknown. Bug seen on FF48.0.2 Win10x64.
                setTimeout(function(){
                    desiredEl.focus();
                },250);
            } else {
                desiredEl.focus();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="test"></input>
```

<sup>Firefox issue: If a <kbd>p</kbd> is typed and focus is immediately changed with `desiredEl.focus();` then the focus is set, but no keyboard input is possible. If there is already content in the `<input>` and focus is moved elsewhere then returned by typing <kbd>p</kbd> keyboard input is possible.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Add `return false` after focusing the field. As has been pointed out in the comments, this will prevent a `p` from ever being typed in the field, even when it is focused. Thus, there may need to be a check for focus as well.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  switch (e.key) {
    case 'p':
      {
        var test = document.getElementById('test');
        if (document.activeElement !== test) { // Make sure it isn't focused already
          test.focus();
          return false;
        }
      }
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="test" />
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Worked great.

Comment: @jrsowles, This solution will prevent you from *ever* typing a `p` into the input field.  Is that acceptable? If so, please state that in the question

Comment: @jrsowles, and Hatchet:  FYI: This code encounters a glitch on Firefox. If a `p` is typed, focus is changed to the `<input>`, but no keyboard input is possible. If the `<input>` already has content then using `p` to return focus to the `<input>` works normally. This does not happen in the JSFiddle. It also happened with my answer in a snippet on Firefox (I added a workaround). It does not happen in Chrome. This appears to be a bug with Firefox and/or/in combination with the Stack Overflow snippet code. jrsowles, If using in production code, you might want to test with your code on Firefox.